# network policy - Kubernetes : Allow traffic from one namespace to pods listening on one port

Tags: kubernetes

I am trying to create a network policy for the following conditions but does not seem to work. What am I doing wrong?  Any help is much appreciated

- create a network policy namespace project-e
- the policy should allow all pods in namespace **project-app** to connect to **port 8000** of Pods in namespace **project-e**
- the policy should not allow access to pods that don't listen on port 8000
- the policy does not allow access from pods that are not in namespace project-app

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: NetworkPolicy
metadata:
  name: test-network-policy
  namespace: project-e
spec:
  podSelector:
    matchLabels: {}
  policyTypes:
  - Ingress
  ingress:
  - from:
    - namespaceSelector:
        matchLabels:
          name: project-app
    - podSelector:
        matchLabels: {}
    ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 8000
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- since you want to allow all the pods from namespace which has a label "name:
  project-app" to namespace  `project-e`.
- You can remove the the  `matchLables:{}` in `podSelector` as following :

```
kind: NetworkPolicy
metadata:
  name: test-network-policy
  namespace: project-e
spec:
  podSelector: {}
  policyTypes:
  - Ingress
  ingress:
  - from:
    - namespaceSelector:
        matchLabels:
          name: project-app
    - podSelector: {}
    ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 8000
```

- Make sure namespace `project-app` has a label `name: project-app`. Otherwise change it to appropriate label in above manifest.

Comment: thanks very much. it works now